# Running ODI Package from Unix Terminal

Tags: unix, terminal, oracle-data-integrator

I want to run the ODI (Oracle Data Integrator) Package from the terminal. I have googled it and all i have came up with is the startscen.sh file which starts the scenario in the ODI from the terminal. Can any one guide me on how to run the ODI Package from the terminal.

Comment: - Which version of ODI do you use?

- What type of agent do you have? Standalone? JEE?
- If you found the documentation about startscen.sh (which is the correct way to go), what is blocking you? It would be easier for us to answer if you have detailed questions. Also please avoid crossposting on other platforms or at least mention it.

Comment: I am using ODI 12c. I have standalone agent. According to the documentation the startscen.sh executable command is: ./startscen.sh <scenario_name> <scenario_version> <context_code> [<log_level>] [-AGENT_URL=<remote_agent_url>] [-ASYNC=yes|no] [-NAME=<local_agent_name>] [-SESSION_NAME=<session_name>] [-KEYWORDS=<keywords>] [<variable>=<value>]* But it is not doing the job for me

Comment: Yes it is indeed the command. Could you please describe the result when you execute that command? Any error message? Please give enough information.

Comment: It is giving this error ./startscenremote.sh: illegal option -- A

Comment: Can you paste your actual command then?

Comment: Issue resolved my command is: ./startscen.sh "-INSTANCE=OracleDIAgent1" TWITTER 001 GLOBAL "-SESSION_NAME=RUN1" "-AGENT_URL=http://localhost:20910/oraclediagent"

Answer (score 1):

startscen.sh will be used to execute a scenario, startloadplan.sh will be used to execute a loadplan and finally startcmd.sh will be used to execute any ODI tools from command prompt, however we can't execute any other objects from command prompt.

mean time would like to understand why do you wanna execute a package, why not scenario?